# Laravel: RewriteRule in .htaccess does not work

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

In my Laravel app I added to the `/public/.htaccess/` file a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/pdf/?$ /about
```

however, if I call `www.mydomain.com/resources/pdf/` the I only get this error:

[image]
 although my server uses APACHE and the other htaccess entries do work. Also `www.mydomain.com/about` does work.

Why is this not working? Here is the full `htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^resources/pdf/?$ /about [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    # [NC] is a case-insensitive match
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/pdf/?$ about [NC]
```

Which works with `www.mydomain.com/resources/pdf/` and `www.mydomain.com/resources/pdf`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, you correctly noticed the additional `/` in my OP,  but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `[L]`:

```
 RewriteRule ^resources/pdf/?$ /about [L]
```

Also I had to clear cache and view the page in incognito mode to witness the effect.